# Scheme: How to convert a charlist to a string

Tags: string, scheme, type-conversion, racket

I am stumped. I am trying to convert a charlist back to a string but it keeps failing: Its stupid because when I paste the result from one function into another it works just fine, but if I do it inside the function it fails...

Example: 
this works

> (delete" h ell o ")
>   outputs: '(#\h #\e #\l #\l #\o)
>   (convertToString '(#\h #\e #\l #\l #\o))
>   outputs: "hello"

but this doesnt work, if the conertToString is called in delete this happens

> (delete" hell  o")
>   outputs:. . list->string: contract violation
>     expected: (listof char?)
>     given: '(#\l . "o")

```
(define deleteCh;driver
  (lambda (s)
    (delete(string->list s))))

(define delete 
  (lambda (input)
    (cond
      [(null? input) input]
      [(equal? (car input) #\space)  (delete (cdr input))]
      [else (convertToString (cons (car input) (delete (cdr input))))])));this works without convertToString 

(define convertToString
  (lambda (charList)
    (list->string charList)))
```

Comment: To convert a list of characters to a string, just use `(apply string lst)`.

Comment: You have posted unreadable code, which is strange since you have tagged racket which has a decent IDE that helps formatting code. `string->list` and `list->string` works, but it has to be a proper list and not a dotted one. Thus last element needs to be `()`

Comment: @Sylwester how is it unreadable? if its because of the spacing, then its my fault since I still have difficulty pasting the code here and making it show up as a code text automatically, even with the 4 spaces/tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with `delete`.  For every char that is not a space you do `convertToString` with the result. Thus with the string "abc" it will do

`(convertToString (cons #\a (convertToString (cons #\b (convertToString (cons #\c '()))))))`

Hint.. You need to do `convertToString` (funny wrapper for `list->string`) with the result in `deleteCh` instead of every subresult.

Comment: OHHHHH I understand you mean now! Thank you! I got it to work now, thanks to your help :D